# Using Sequelize Hooks and Crypto to Encrypt User Passwords

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I got the below codes from the post https://medium.com/@benjaminpwagner/using-sequelize-hooks-and-crypto-to-encrypt-user-passwords-5cf1a27513d9. But

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const db = require('./db.js')
const User = db.define('user', {
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        get() {
            return () => this.getDataValue('password')
        }
    },
    salt: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        get() {
            return() => this.getDataValue('salt')
        }
    }
})


#FUNCTIONS UNDER USER CLASS
User.generateSalt = function() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')
}
User.encryptPassword = function(plainText, salt) {
    return crypto
        .createHash('RSA-SHA256')
        .update(plainText)
        .update(salt)
        .digest('hex')
}

const setSaltAndPassword = user => {
    if (user.changed('password')) {
        user.salt = User.generateSalt()
        user.password = User.encryptPassword(user.password(), user.salt())
    }
}
User.beforeCreate(setSaltAndPassword)
User.beforeUpdate(setSaltAndPassword)
```

What this.getDataValue('password') does?

Answer (score 1):

`getDataValue` is to get the underlying value because using `this.password` instead of `getDataValue('password')` in the password's getter will lead to infinite recursion: the getter will call itself.
See [getDataValue](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#instance-method-getDataValue) in the official documentation.